# Is there a function in dart to remove substring with pattern?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to remove a pattern string from a string.

`[Armor] Reset the Cooldown of Rocket Boots after falling to or below {scale=10|10}% Health.`

I know how to remove the pattern, but i need to get the pattern before remove it.

In this case i need something like these.

`var pattern = text.getSubstring(new RegExp(r'\{.*?\}'));`

Is there a function that can get a substring with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want but you can use an instance of `RegExp` to match against a String like:

```
void main() {
  print(RegExp(r'\{.*?\}')
      .firstMatch(
          '[Armor] Reset the Cooldown of Rocket Boots after falling to or below {scale=10|10}% Health.')
      .group(0)); // {scale=10|10}
}
```